How to use Rexx in Eclipse
How to access Rexx using Eclipse. We are using Eclipse to access to mainframe, so all the Rexx tools we created in Z/OS is wasted, so trying to see any options to use those Rexx programs?
Googled and found some tutorial about a Rexx plugin "NetRexx" and "OORexx" , but even that tutorial does not contain how it works and what will be the output.
Has anyone have any information regarding this? please let know. Any help would be appreciated.
What I expect is Run the Rexx in Eclipse IDE and the output should be same as in Z/OS. like expanding the copybook, and etc.

By Eclipse do you mean standard Eclipse without mainframe related plugins on top of it?
If you have IBM Developer for z/OS plugins installed on top of regular Eclipse, you might be able to use a feature called Menu Manager, to define custom actions that invoke Rexx or regular TSO commands. More info here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/developer-for-zos/16.0?topic=functions-creating-menu-actions-in-menu-manager
Most likely you will need help from your z/OS System Programmers to customize menu manager for your site.
